# JFLEX installation error

Tags: jflex

I am trying to install JFLEX on my windows 8 64-bit desktop, in order to do some university coursework.

I have downloaded the files and then performed the following steps:

Opened the batch file named JFLEX, at the following address:

```
C:\Users\ALEXOM\Documents\jflex-1.4.3\jflex-1.4.3\bin
```

I right clicked and chose the option to edit, which opened notepad:

I then changed the following 2 lines:

```
set JFLEX_HOME=C:\Users\ALEXOM\Documents\jflex-1.4.3\jflex
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\ALEXOM\Downloads
```

The second line is the folder that contains the file:

```
jdk-7u40-windows-x64
```

I then saved and closed this file and double clicked the batch file that I have just edited.

It opens a command prompt which says:

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

This window then closes instantly

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I was just working on this yesterday, it required that JAVA_HOME was the jdk directory itself. So, I would suggest trying

```
set JFLEX_HOME=C:\Users\ALEXOM\Documents\jflex-1.4.3\jflex
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\ALEXOM\Downloads\jdk-7u40-windows-x64
```

Hopefully this works